# What does GOAT or 'GOATing' mean?

Tags: guild-wars-2, terminology

I've heard this a few times in Guild Wars 2, usually in the context of a [PvP](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Player_versus_Player) or [WvW](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/World_versus_World) match.

Someone will be complaining that

> There was too much goating in that match

or

> That guy is a professional goat

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion I got from someone in-game was [Greatest Of All Time](http://www.internetslang.com/GOAT-meaning-definition.asp)

Indicating a player who was playing really well.

So

> There was too much goating in that match

could mean there were several players in a PvP match that were untouchable.

I just can't remember what context I heard it in.

Comment: That was actually the full name of the guild I mentioned in my other comment :) so while their name was "greatest of all time",they did not seem to be THAT great.

Answer (score 2):

It's something I rarely hear, but associated with multiplayer online games (especially PvP in with objectives) it usually means [scapegoating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapegoating).

Now I haven't played a lot of GW2 but in WoW PvP or LoL matches you sometimes accuse someone of goating if he blames another teammate or his internet connection.

For the term "He's a professional goat"... well I've never heard that to be honest but I think it's someone who always blames others.